Deploying Django Channel Application with Nginx and Daphne
I am trying to deploy a Django Channel Application with Daphne and nginx. I am getting 502 Bad Gateway  error when I try to access the application from a web browser.
I am using AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance to host the web application. Following is my nginx config file.
    upstream channels-backend {server localhost:8000;}
        
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.77.249.57;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
         
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }

Following is my daphne.service file.
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
Requires=daphne.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/project
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/project/env/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 
chat_service.asgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Do you have any idea to solve the issue ?

Your gunicorn service is crashing, examine the logs with this command: journalctl --unit=gunicorn | tail -n 300
